# PHPMailer attachments issue

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, crud

I am trying to create a program to send emails with PHPMailer and I am having a problem.

I am implementing a simple CRUD with HTML that sends it's content via POST Method to the PHP file that execute the PHPMailer. But the problem is that I want to send a file (for example a Microsoft Word file) via the CRUD and it's not working.

Here is my code...

THE HTML CRUD

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Send email</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>SEND EMAIL</h1>
        <br><br>
        <form action="email.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label>Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Message</label>
                <input type="text" name="message">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Attach file</label>
                <input type="file" name="file">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

THE PHPMailer implementation

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                    
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
    $mail->Username   = 'myemail@gmail.com';                   
    $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';                            
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;         
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            
    $mail->Port       = 587; 

    $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('mailreceiver@gmail.com'); 

    $mail->isHTML(true);    
    
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $mail->Body = $_POST['message'];

    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']);  THIS IS WHAT DONT WORK 

    $mail->send();

    echo("Email has been send");

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo("Error couldn't send the mail");
}

?>
```

Everything works perfectly without the implementation of the $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']);

But when I try to implement the part to attach a file it seems to be
inaccessible for the PHPMailer

So, ¿How can I fix this? I want to attach a file to the PHPMailer with the HTML CRUD

Comment: You keep saying “CRUD”, which might be part of your overall project, but nothing in your code or problem appears to be related to CRUD. Instead, it appears you are having problems sending email attachments with PHPMailer. Is that correct? If so, do you have PHP error reporting enabled, and have you checked the PHP and PHPMailer logs?

Comment: `addAttachment($_FILES['file'])` You are directly providing the php's temp path I think that won't work since it has some restrictions regarding the usage in common functions that's why you should [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to regular folder first and then you can use it like a regular file
UPDATE: You can try `addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])`  (https://www.thaicreate.com/upload/tutorial/php-file2.jpg?v=1001) may be it should work

Comment: Your code is unsafe. Follow the [send uploaded file example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v6.6.2/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer.